# How to update multiple arrays in separate object

Tags: mongodb

Hi let's say that I have these 3 objects in a collection

```
{
  id: 1,
  users: ['sam', 'john', 'lizy'],
  isActive: false,
}, {
  id: 2,
  users: ['sam', 'mathew', 'chandler'],
  isActive: false,
}, {
  id: 3,
  users: ['monica', 'rachel', 'sam'],
  isActive: false,
}
```

I want to update collection where id is `1` and `2`. The only update I want it in the users array I want to replace "sam" with "superman"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) as well as [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in order to match both documents:

```
db.getCollection('collection').updateMany(
  { "id": { "$in": [1,2] }, "users": "sam"  },
  { "$set": { "users.$": "superman" } }
)
```

Note that without the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) it's still going to update `"sam"` even though it's in a different array position.

The key part to working with the positional operator is that something needs to match the array "position", so we include `"users": "sam"` within the query conditions. This translates `$` to be the "matched position" of the element in the array when the operation ( [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) in this case ) is applied.

Note also `.updateMany()` is the modern driver equivalent to `.update()` with [`{ "multi": true }`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) always set to on.

Comment: Thank you bro, this helped. Cheers ^_^